# A general approach to getting around model packages which cannot handle rank deficiency

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling, algorithms

A few packages which employ variations of generalized linear models (`pscl` and `VGAM`), specifically the functions `hurdle()`, `zeroinfl()` and `vglm()`. When a model formula is rank deficient, these functions give an error message. I'm guessing this happens for other modelling packages - any ideas for a general workaround for this type of problem?

Definitely have to thank all the package maintainers for the listed packages - I hope this doesn't come across as complaining! I'm also aware of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it) question, trying to think a general code-based approach.