# lme4_fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset consisting of the following: one column `language` containing five different languages. Two other columns `Canonicity` and `Intrinsic` containing either (0, 1). One last column, `useOfIntrinsic`. You can view the data [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1phjnQNsSawpbX-7TSCVcjWsqHuMAWu14W4RwnCSccFk/edit#gid=0).

I would like to test the use of intrinsic as a function of `Language`, `Canonicity` and `useOfIntrinsic`. Thus, I ran the following mixed-effect logistic regression model:

```
glmer(INT ~ Language * Canonicity + Language + Canonicity + useOfIntrinsic +
      (1|Picture) + (1|ID), data = data, family = "binomial")
```

I also tried:

```
glmer(INT ~ Language + Canonicity + useOfIntrinsic:Language + Canonicity:CAN +
      useOfIntrinsic + (1|Picture) + (1|ID), data = data, family = "binomial")
```

However, I get this error:

> fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient

I do not get the error when I exclude the `useOfIntrinsic` factor. This factor is basically is the count of `intrinsic==1` for each `Language`. I add this factor in order to test whether overall use of intrinsic is a good predictor `intrinsic`.

There are other post that talk about this error (e.g. [What is rank deficiency, and how to deal with it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it)) but I am still unable to fix the error.

Another related question is whether I should reduce the significance level when running the same model 5 times (or order to change the reference language group)?

Answer (score 7):

In the data you link to, `Language` and `useOfIntrinsic` encode the exact same information.  Think about it this way: `Language` gives the anova flexibility to estimate the mean for each language independently.  Once this has been done, there is no additional among-language variation floating around to estimate the effect of `useOfIntrinsic`.  Or think about it this way: imagine that the effect of `useOfIntrinsic` is absolutely anything you'd like.  The model can't know if you're right or wrong, because whatever predictions it makes about each language based on `useOfIntrinsic`, it can just use the effect of `Language` to offset those predictions and give the correct group mean.  So there's no way to estimate the `useOfIntrinsic` effect when `Language` is also in the model.

One final way to think about it.  You can think of the model you are trying to fit as asking for an estimate of the effect of `useOfIntrinsic` while controlling for the effect of `Language`.  But once you've controlled for the effect of `Language`, you've already completely dealt with the differences between languages that you might want to attribute to `useOfIntrinsic`.  To put both variables in a single model, you either need some independent variation in the two variables (i.e. some variation in `useOfIntrinsic` within a single language), or you need to place some additional constraints on how you estimate the effect of `Language`.  One possibility would be to experiment with estimating `Language` as a random effect, but I don't necessarily recommend this given that you only have five languages in the sample.

You do not need to apply any correction for changing which language is the reference group.  This is not a situation where you are estimating five different models--this is just five different parameterizations of the exact same model. You are looking at the exact same results five different ways.  The results will be the exact same each time, up to the appropriate constants involved in the reparameterization.

Comment: Totally make sense. I instead used the frequency of intrinsic use per subject. The model works fine with that. However, I get the same error if I scaled this factor 'log(data$useOfInt)', I am wondering why is that? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure i follow what a subject is in this model, or what model exactly is producing the error.  If you run the exact same model as above but replacing `data$useOfInt` with its logarithm, it still has the same problem as before--every language has exactly one value of `log(data$useOfInt)` associated with it, so you can't put both that and `language` in a single model.

Comment: Also, just for clarity and brevity of code, you don't need to include both `Language * Canonicity` and `Language + Canonicity` in your model. `Language * Canonicity` is equivalent to `Language + Canonicity + Language:Canonicity`, where `Language:Canonicity` is the interaction effect between language and canonicity. :)