# Replicating Stata pweight in R

Tags: r, regression, stata, fixed-effects-model

I'm trying to replicate some Stata results in **R** and am having trouble interpreting the different outcome. For reproducible example, I'm using the API data from the survey package.

```
 data(api, package = 'survey')
 df <- apistrat[, c('api00', 'ell', 'meals', 'mobility', 'cname', 'pw')]
 df$cname <- ifelse(df$cname %in% c('Fresno', 'Santa Clara', 'San Bernadino'), 
                    'Group1', 'Group2')
```

In **R**:

```
y <- felm(api00 ~ ell + meals + mobility|cname|0|cname, data=df, weights=df$pw)
summary(y)

Call:
   felm(formula = api00 ~ ell + meals + mobility|cname|0|cname, data=df, weights=df$pw) 

Weighted Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1076.96  -317.47   -87.58   217.20  1164.29 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Cluster s.e. t value Pr(>|t|)    
ell       -0.5139       0.6136  -0.837   0.4033    
meals     -3.1483       0.3341  -9.424   <2e-16 ***
mobility   0.2347       0.1071   2.192   0.0296 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 404 on 195 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared(full model): 0.6601   Adjusted R-squared: 0.6531 
Multiple R-squared(proj model): 0.6496   Adjusted R-squared: 0.6425 
F-statistic(full model, *iid*):94.68 on 4 and 195 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16 
F-statistic(proj model): 0.2338 on 3 and 1 DF, p-value: 0.8695
```

In Stata:

```
areg api00 ell meals mobility [pw=pw], absorb(cname) vce(cl cname)

Linear regression, absorbing indicators         Number of obs     =        200
Absorbed variable: cname                        No. of categories =          2
                                                F(   1,      1)   =          .
                                                Prob > F          =          .
                                                R-squared         =     0.6601
                                                Adj R-squared     =     0.6531
                                                Root MSE          =    72.2192

                                  (Std. Err. adjusted for 2 clusters in cname)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       api00 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         ell |   -.513901   .6136284    -0.84   0.556    -8.310789    7.282987
       meals |  -3.148314   .3340804    -9.42   0.067    -7.393208     1.09658
    mobility |   .2346743   .1070769     2.19   0.273    -1.125866    1.595215
       _cons |   821.8216    .237367  3462.24   0.000     818.8056    824.8376
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**R** and Stata return same estimates, clustered SE, and t-value, but different p-values. Specifically, meals and mobility are significant predictors according to **R**, but not according to Stata.

Can anyone advise me on what is causing the difference?

Comment: How can t-stats replicate but not p-values as latter uses former as test statistic? Please post actual regression results in body of question for both R and Stata.

Comment: This is very interesting. Stata is reporting a high t-stat (-9.42) not close to zero. There also is a note reported regarding standard errors. Also, your Stata model does not report an F-test result. See [this Statalist thread](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/921694-no-f-test-value). R's `felm` may handle clustering differently especially with *full model* and *proj model*. Also, I would play around with Stata's weights (`aw`, `pw`, `fw`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've attempted to specify `felm` as a fixed effects model, which makes not much sense since you have no panel data in long format.

In your case Stata's `areg` does nothing more than omitting dummies from the output. So you could just use `reg` by taking up the dummy, i.e. `reg api00 ell meals mobility cname [pw=pw], vce(cl cname)` gives you (apart from the Intercept statistic) the same results.

So correctly you need to specify the model in R with `lm` and a dummy variable.

```
f <- lm(api00 ~ ell + meals + mobility + factor(cname), weights=pw, data=df)
```

Which results with cluster robust standard errors (`HC1` for the Stata ones):

```
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
coeftest(f, vcov=vcovHC(f, type="HC1", cluster="cname"))
# t test of coefficients:
#  
#                      Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)         830.43035   21.18687  39.1955   <2e-16 ***
# ell                  -0.51390    0.40640  -1.2645   0.2076    
# meals                -3.14831    0.29258 -10.7606   <2e-16 ***
# mobility              0.23467    0.40471   0.5799   0.5627    
# factor(cname)Group2  -9.70819   19.92028  -0.4874   0.6266    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This brings us already closer to the Stata result. However, as *@Parfait* already commented, the missing *F*-statistic signals an issue with the model or the sufficiency of the data. Also the Intercept statistics of `areg` (*t=* `3462.24`) is suspect. If you look closely, `summary(y)` of your `felm` estimation also throws you:

```
Warning message:
In chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) :
  the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

That means the estimated varicance-covariance matrix is not of sufficient rank to perform the model test (see [this answer on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35077/163114)). (Note that `lm` doesn't throw a warning!)

In such a case we could bootstrap the standard errors. However, there is no agreement how to bootstrap with weighted data (see e.g. [this Stata list post](https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2007-03/msg00383.html)). At least we could compare the bootstrapped confidence intervals of unweighted data of both Stata and R.

*Stata:*

```
. set seed 42

. reg api00 ell meals mobility cname, vce(boot, reps(999))
[...]    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |   Observed   Bootstrap                         Normal-based
       api00 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         ell |  -.6955824   .4582103    -1.52   0.129    -1.593658    .2024932
       meals |  -2.865973   .3136513    -9.14   0.000    -3.480718   -2.251227
    mobility |   .0238613   .5340762     0.04   0.964    -1.022909    1.070631
       cname |  -12.82289   20.51538    -0.63   0.532     -53.0323    27.38652
       _cons |   820.3156   41.34835    19.84   0.000     739.2743    901.3569
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*R:*

```
BFX <- function(data, indicies) lm(api00 ~ ell + meals + mobility + factor(cname), 
                                    data=data[indicies, ])$coef
library(boot)
set.seed(42)
b <- boot(df, BFX, R=999)
t(sapply(1:5, function(x) boot.ci(b, type = c("norm"), index=x)$normal))
#      [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
# [1,] 0.95 765.343516 851.0541280  # Intercept
# [2,] 0.95  -1.594969   0.2126469  # ell
# [3,] 0.95  -3.490491  -2.2411083  # meals
# [4,] 0.95  -1.042949   1.0105038  # mobility
# [5,] 0.95 -53.473958  27.6272014  # cname
```

As we can see, the confidence intervals are pretty close, and we may conclude that the `lm` further above with dummy variable and weights seems to be the right choice. However, as said maybe you should reconsider the clustering in your model.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question, which is why the Stata p-values differ from those in R.