# Using regularization with logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, regularization

I have a data set of 3000 observations with 9 variables, and I'm trying to predict whether water are safe for drinking.
Regular multivariate logistic regression isn't that good at forecasting, and also none of the coefficients is significant, even if I run univariate logistic regression.
This is why I thought of regularization, but I wasn't able to found an explanation of this and when it is appropriate to use.
Also, if it exists, if be happy for a reference to R functions.

Comment: Is your measured response variable binary or some measure of contamination (e.g., 6 parts per million coronavirus).

Comment: It is binary: safe or not safe

Comment: plenty of regularised glm out there i believe. Glmnet is quite popular and has vignette. 
However, do you have any expectation of what the relationship is between inputs and "safe"eg I could imagine not safe to drink is "legally" defined as chemical 1> conc1 or chemical2 > conc 2 or chemical 3 > conc3. I don't believe you can fit this in a logistic regression (without adding some nonlinearities).

Comment: Statistical significance has nothing to do with regularization and forecasting. What doesn’t work about forecasting with logistic regression for you?

Comment: This is mostly an exercise at class. There are all kind of substances and measures like Chloramines and pH levels. The prediction is around 58% accuracy, which is quite poor in such cases, as it is health issues.

Answer (score 1):

Regularisation aims at reducing the effects of design matrix being overdetermined or [underdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system), recall solving $Ax=b$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$. Regularisation is appropriate to use if $p>>m$ (underdetermined) or $p<<m$ (overdetermined). Here the case is $m>>p$, overdetermined (m=3000, p=9 in this case).

Using [LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) or [elastic net regularisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization) are recommended instead of plain logistic regression. Without regularisation, solution may not be correct. [glmnet's introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet.pdf) will give a good idea how to use LASSO and elastic-net regularisations.

See also [rank deficiency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it).

Comment: Agreed on glmnet—and just to add on, for a general background into what the LASSO does conceptually, I recommend *Introduction to Statistical Learning* by James et al. The R labs are outdated, but the concepts are explained in an intuitive and accessible way.

Comment: It’s just been updated with a new edition. Haven’t checked the R labs but presumably they’ve been updated, too.