# Added more data and suddenly GLMM fails to converge (R)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have a dataset where I randomly sampled housing developments, and then within these I systematically sampled every habitat patch. I now have a dataset where each observation is a patch_ID, and I have variables recorded for the patch such as project_ID (the development it came from), Area_ha (the area of the patch, in hectares), Pre_post (whether the patch is from a pre-development site plan or a post-development one). I would like to conduct a GLMM to investigate whether there is a difference between the size (Area_ha) of habitat patches before and after development (eg. "pre" or "post" in the Pre_post variable), whilst accounting for my grouping factor (project_ID). I am using a GLMM as my Area_ha data are heavily right skewed and have no zero values. Area is continuous, Pre_post is a factor with two levels ("pre", "post"), and project_ID is a factor with 25 levels (each of the 25 developments).

I successfully conducted this GLMM on a smaller dataset last month, using the code:

```
glmm_gamma <- glmer(Area_ha ~ Pre_post + (1 | project_ID), 
                    family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
                    data = size3)
```

However, now I have increased the size of my dataset, and the same line of code as above to run the model is giving me the error:

```
Warning: Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0209587 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

The data is still right skewed and I have removed the most troublesome outlier.

I have tried the following options to troubleshoot but to no avail:

```
#To rescale and centre my stuff:
mu <- mean(size3$Area_ha, na.rm = TRUE)
sigma <- sd(size3$Area_ha, na.rm = TRUE)
size3$Area_ha_scaled <- (size3$Area_ha - mu) / sigma
#But I then realised I can't do this because gamma distributions don't allow for negative values
```

Trying to check singularity:

```
tt <- getME(glmm_gamma,"theta")
ll <- getME(glmm_gamma,"lower")
min(tt[ll==0])
#0.8909557, so no worry of singularity
```

Trying with more iterations

```
glmm_gamma <- glmer(Area_ha ~ Pre_post + (1 | project_ID), 
                    family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
                    data = size3,
                    control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1000000)))
#Still didn't work
```

I'm completely stumped for what to do next, and would really appreciate some help! I'm confused as to why adding more data has made my model stop working completely - I'm not very confident at statistics so hopefully this community can help!

I have put my data here - both the data and some of my code: https://github.com/sirianmckellen/stackex.git
If anyone has any ideas on how I can move forward, whether this is a solvable issue or whether I need a new model type (if so, what should I consider?), etc, I'd be SO grateful! Thank you all!

Comment: For Data sharing see here: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5258/341520

Comment: Thank you! I have made a GitHub folder (I think!) with my data in and my example code in. Do let me know if this works :)

Comment: Fitting GLMMs is not plug-and-play statistics. It is not true that "adding more data" will in general improve fitting algorithms. In this answer, I cover several diagnostic plots in the context of mixed modeling to assess the quality and reliability of fits https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it/151116#151116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlier deletion is questionable at the best of times, as it is basically throwing way information, but in your case you detect 10% of your data as outliers, which is just unacceptable. Also if you already want to use a statistical model for skewed data, then don't classify outliers with symmetric criterion. On a log-scale your data is fine.

Now since the GLMM does converge if we don't remove the "outliers" I checked with  `DHARMa` to compare the Data against a simulated Data from the model and we can see, that gamma is a bad fit. To be precise, it is actually insufficiently right skewed, which explains why the outlier removed data doesn't converge at all anymore. I guess the folk theorem of statistical computing holds: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2008/05/13/the_folk_theore/

[image]

A log-normal model however does great. Note that a sigma of 1 on a log scale is a lot of variation.

```r
library(lme4)
library(DHARMa)

size2 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sirianmckellen/stackex/main/Size2.csv")
size2 <- size2[!is.na(size2$project_ID), ]
size_quartiles <- quantile(size2$Area_ha, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = TRUE)
size_quartiles

size_IQR <- IQR(size2$Area_ha, na.rm = TRUE)

size_Lower <- size_quartiles[1] - 1.5*size_IQR
size_Upper <- size_quartiles[2] + 1.5*size_IQR

size3 <- subset(size2, size2$Area_ha > size_Lower & size2$Area_ha < size_Upper)

table(size2$project_ID) - table(size3$project_ID)
glmm_gamma <- glmer(Area_ha ~ Pre_post + (1 | project_ID), 
                    family = Gamma(link = "log"), 
                    data = size2)
summary(glmm_gamma)
#glmm_gamma@optinfo
#sessionInfo()

m2 <- lmer(log(Area_ha) ~ Pre_post + (1 | project_ID), 
           data = size2)
summary(m2)
confint(m2)
res_gamma <- simulateResiduals(glmm_gamma)
plot(res_gamma, title = "Gamma")
res_lognormal <- simulateResiduals(m2)
plot(res_lognormal, title = "log-normal")

# a plot for your consideration
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(size2, aes(y = Area_ha, x = as_factor(project_ID), color = Pre_post)) +
  geom_boxplot(varwidth = T) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help. I'm very new to statistics and only fit a GLMM as I'd read it could be a good fit, so this is hugely helpful. Could you possibly point me towards some resources on how to interpret linear mixed model outputs when values are logged? I assume some kind of back transformation might be needed for my p values, effect sizes, etc? Thank you!!

Comment: @sirianmckellan p-values don't need back transformation, but `lmer` doesn't provide for technical reasons(https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/22988/341520). Also I think confidence Intervals are superior.

Comment: @sirianmckellan Other then that you need to understand that everything is multiplicative, i.e. pre has linear effect 0.34 95% CI (-0.02 - 0.68) meaning ratios of 1.38 (0.97 - 1.98) or +38% (-3% - +98%). The sigmas can be reinterpreted from +/- to $\cdot / \div$ the exponent.