# how to calculate VIF in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, variance-inflation-factor

No book told me that...

Using McFadden’s Pseudo-R2 ? OR do traditional linear regression to get VIF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variance inflation factor is only about the independent variables. You can calculate it the same way in linear regression, logistic regression, Poisson regression etc.

Whether the same values indicate the same degree of "trouble" from colinearity is another matter. For this, I like to use the `perturb` package in `R` which looks at the practical effects of one of the main issues with colinearity: That a small change in the input data can make a large change in the parameter estimates.

Comment: "That a small change in the input data can make a large change in the parameter estimates"            Is it because of the variance is usually very large for highly correlated variable? By changing the observation matrix X a little, we artificially create  a new sample and hope the new estimation will be differ a lot from the original one?

Comment: Someone else can give the math, if you need it. Intuitively, it's because the variance doesn't know where to go.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on VIF mentions ordinary least squares and the coefficient of determination. If you were doing a logistic regression and wanted to find the VIFs of the independent values, does this mean you perform an auxiliary standard linear regression?