# Why we use Ridge regression instead of Least squares in Multicollinearity?

Tags: self-study, least-squares, multicollinearity, bias, ridge-regression

Why do we use Ridge regression instead of Least squares in Multicollinearity?

Which one is correct:

a. lower bias and higher variance
b. lower bias with the same variance
c. higher bias  with a lower variance
d. the same bias with lower variance

Comment: Which is correct: I should eat an apple, or I should eat an orange? They are both correct, for different situations. Sometimes you don't mind a bit of bias, sometimes you do.

Comment: Is this an exercise/exam question? If so, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: @JeremyMiles, in this situation the answers are not equally correct, because the situation is well defined: multicollinearity.

Comment: Oh, thanks. You're right, I should have read the question more closely.

Comment: You do not need to put [solved] in the title. There is an accepted answer, it means that this is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would we use ridge regression? It's useful because it **prevents overfit** to your training data. Now, ask yourself how does preventing overfit influence bias and variance.

I have a useful link for you: [When to use regularization methods for regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/when-to-use-regularization-methods-for-regression)

[image]

Comment: ok got it! It's higher bias with a lower variance ! Right @student T?

Comment: @Mike Yes. You learn.

Comment: @Mike It's time for you to appreciate our efforts. Please accept an answer, myself or Taylor. This is an opportunity for you to appreciate our efforts. You should see a green tick near our answers. Please pick one.

Answer (score 4):

Your OLS estimator is 
$$
\hat{\beta}_{ols} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y,
$$
while your ridge regression estimator is 
$$
\hat{\beta}_{ridge} = (X'X + \lambda I)^{-1}X'y.
$$
Take the expectation and variance of each one, and then compare your results.

Comment: ok got it! It's higher bias with a lower variance ! Right @Taylor?

Comment: @Mike that's right