# Strategy to analyze large ( 20 mill rows and 200 columns) to predict a single variable

Tags: data-transformation, dataset, large-data, high-dimensional

I am curious to understand how data scientists attack exceedingly large datasets in order to build a regression model for y?

How does one decide where to start from?
Reduce a large number of columns without the benefit of domain knowledge?
Basic stats like removing - large number of null columns , single values aside what other steps do data scientists usually use ?

Comment: 200 variables given your sample size is not that many. What you want: explanatory or predictive model? You can simply use regularized regression.

Comment: How does regularized expression help in reducing the manual work of going through 200 columns ?

Comment: Regularization does automatic feature selection https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4272/35989