# Is it useful to use sparse regression (e.g. Lasso) when the number of observations is significantly larger than the number of covariates?

Tags: regression, lasso, sparse, regularization

I'm learning about penalized/sparse regression and I noticed that the examples used for penalized/sparse regression, e.g. Lasso, are usually cases where the number of observations is significantly smaller than the number of covariates/independent variables/predictors, $n << p$.

I was wondering if it would still be useful to apply such methods to datasets where we also have a large number of $p$ but the number of observations $n$ is significantly larger, $n >> p$.

For reference, we have a dataset that has $n = 19,051$ observations and each observation has $p = 336$ predictors.

Comment: Based on many other posts here, ridge (or elasicnet) will probably be better than lasso for your case.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/when-to-use-regularization-methods-for-regression