# Bayesian Regression: Loss Function Explained

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian

Considering a simple linear regression model e.g. $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon $ , in probabilistic terms:
$$ \mu_i = \alpha + \beta x_i  $$
$$ y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma) $$

We assume prior distributions on the parameters $\alpha, \beta, \sigma$ and apply Bayes theorem (posterior $\propto$ likelihood x prior) i.e.:

$$f(\alpha, \beta, \sigma | Y, X) \propto  \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathcal{N}(y_i; \alpha + \beta x_i, \sigma)  f_\alpha(\alpha)f_\beta(\beta) f_\sigma (\sigma)$$

With priors and data, we then perform Markov Chain Monte Carlo method for sampling from this posterior distribution.

My question is:

- How do loss functions or different loss functions fit into this picture? How do loss functions come into the next stage of taking a decision based on the posterior distrubtion?

Comment: Loss functions come into the next stage, where you take a decision based on the posterior distribution, using the loss function to help decide which decision is optimal.

Comment: That is useful thanks @Henry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do loss functions or different loss functions fit into this picture? Do different loss functions result in a different mechanism for calculating likelihood?

This is how I read your question: we could fit regression by minimizing different loss functions, how they can be applied to Bayesian regression?

Regression, in non-Bayesian setting, can be fitted by minimizing loss or [maximizing the likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms). Both approaches are equivalent, for example, minimizing squared loss is equivalent to maximizing Gaussian likelihood, absolute loss is equivalent to using Laplace distribution for likelihood, etc. Same in [Bayesian regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252577/bayes-regression-how-is-it-done-in-comparison-to-standard-regression/252608#252608), you are not minimizing the loss to fit the model, but the choice of likelihood function plays a similar role.

Same applies to using regularization. In Bayesian setting, regularization is dealt by choosing appropriate priors. For example, $\ell_2$ penalty is equivalent to [using Gaussian priors for the parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/328342/is-bayesian-ridge-regression-another-name-of-bayesian-linear-regression/328345#328345).