# When should you use L1 vs. L2 regularization?

Tags: lasso, regularization, ridge-regression, elastic-net

Can't seem to find a good explanation online of **concrete examples** of where you would use one over the other?

I also read somewhere that L1 is supposedly slower than L2, but not sure how that is since L2 involves squaring and L1 is just taking the absolute value.

Comment: Pretty big question so oversimplifying things for a comment here: L1 helps with explanatory variable selection while L2 helps with explanatory variables' covariances. L2 has a closed-form solution too so it can be often much faster to compute. Be without much context I would suggest using the "cheat code" and perform elastic-net. :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'L2 helps with explanatory variables' covariances'?

Comment: When we have collinearities and/or explanatory variables that are somehow interconnected, L2 helps us get more robust (and "shrunk") coefficients.

Comment: [Not sure this is a duplicate, but maybe…](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/331809/247274)

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate of [When should I use lasso vs ridge?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/866/when-should-i-use-lasso-vs-ridge)

Comment: If I remember correctly, Tibshirani's original paper where he proposed lasso contains some illuminating comparisons with ridge.